# регулярка допускающая ввод только русских букв и дефис?

Tags: javascript

регулярка допускающая ввод только русских букв и дефис, то есть если пользователь ввел что-то отличное от русский и дефис, то заменять на ""

Comment: Дайте примеры валидных, и не валидных строк.

Answer (score 2):

Само регулярное выражение:

```
/[^а-яА-ЯёЁ\-]/g
```

Его использование:

```js
var str = "фавы-пfgd123vcаыв@пёЁв-ыаАВЫВЫadasf-gdvcfОt424";
console.log(str.replace(/[^а-яА-ЯёЁ\-]/g, ''));
```

Также хочу вам сообщить- если вы не будете принимать отправленные ответы как принятые- участники сообщества перестанут вам помогать.